# Clip Planes issues

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, image3d

I want to plot a schematic diagram of this

[image] or
[image]

So far, I am able to plot this[image] using the code provided below.

I am having a problem with `ClipPlanes`

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -4}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1], Axes -> True, 
 ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[{{2.5, 2.5, 2.5}, {2.5, 3, 3}, {5, 5, 
      5}}], Rotate[
    InfinitePlane[{{2.5, 2.5, 2.5}, {0, 0.25, 3}, {0, 0, 5}}], 
    180*Degree, {0, 0, 1}]}]
```

Please do help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using `HalfSpace` can clip the solid of cylinder.

```
cylin0 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -4}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1];
cylin1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[cylin0, MaxCellMeasure -> .01];
space1 = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[HalfSpace[{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}], 
   PlotRange -> 200];
space2 = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[HalfSpace[{1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, 0}], 
   PlotRange -> 200];
Graphics3D[{{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[{Opacity[.9], Lighter@Cyan}], 
   RegionIntersection[cylin1, space1, 
    space2]}, {{AbsolutePointSize[10], Red, Point[{1, 0, 0}]}, 
   Opacity[.2], cylin0}}, Lighting -> "ThreePoint", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- Using four `ClipPlane` to get another result.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
cylin0 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -4}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1];
Graphics3D[{{ClipPlanes -> {Flatten@{-{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1} . {1, 0, 
         0}}, Flatten@{-{1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1} . {1, 0, 0}}}, Cyan, 
   cylin0}, {ClipPlanes -> 
    Flatten@{{1, 0, 1}, -{1, 0, 1} . {1, 0, 0}}, Opacity[.2], cylin0, 
   ClipPlanes -> Flatten@{{1, 0, -1}, -{1, 0, -1} . {1, 0, 0}}, 
   cylin0}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]